# Eclipse & Java: make Eclipse also compile the code when run

Tags: java, eclipse

Note: I just started using Eclipse, so bear with me.

When I run a program in Eclipse, I see that it does not automatically compile the class file (using JDK 14); I have to manually run `javac` every time. I have "Build Automatically" checked as well. How do I make Eclipse compile the class file automatically when run?

Comment: Did you create a "Java Project"? In that case there should be a "J" in the project icon. If not, then it won't recognize it as a Java project and it won't try and build anything.

Comment: Yes, I did create a Java project.

Comment: Sorry, just reread your question. What's that about JDK 14? That's not just old, that's ancient. Any reason why you're not using Java 8 or 13 or something similar? If you're going that far back, you might need to use an Eclipse from the stone age as well. Eclipse uses it's own parser / compiler after all, not `javac`...

Comment: Just a wild guess, but note that eclipse as default don't place the .class files(The compiled code) in the same directory as the source code. So if you want to run the program from the command line, you should navigate to the bin directory. To run the app from eclipse, try to right click on the app in the left menu, and choose "Run as" -> Java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse *does* automatically compile the class file, every time you save any sourec file.

Some things to check:

1. The java file has to be in a 'source folder'. Check this; you can right click the project, select 'properties...' and look at the build path settings, which has a section for source paths.
2. Each source path has an associated target dir. By default, this is named `bin`. *THAT* is what where your auto-compiled-on-save class files are at.
3. If all is set up properly, you can right click any java file with a 'main' method from e.g. the package explorer, select 'debug' from there, and see it in action. If you then make an edit to a file and save, it'll update automatically. Thus, write something like:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            System.out.println("Ping123");
        }
    }
}
```

run it, then edit the string literal, hit save, and you'll see the new string show up immediately, without compiling anything, without restarting anything. If that's *NOT* happening, you haven't properly configured the project.

Comment: As long as "Build Automatically" is set on the project, which should always be set in any normal situation.